# Trying to display a hyperlink in dataframe in python where the data frame is saved as an html file through code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add hyperlink in an html page. The html page has the content which is dataframe. The html page is saved in EFS through python code. When I am adding the link in the data frame, its getting displayed as text, not as a href link.

```py
df.insert(2, "Jira Link", [dict(name='Google', url='http://www.google.com'), 23, 24, 21, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], True)
    df.style.format({'url': make_clickable})
    print("Jira Link===")
    print(df)
def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val, val)

df.style.format({'url': make_clickable})
```

In another file I am saving the html file as :

```py
with open(efsPath+"/"+error_file, "w") as file:
       file.write(message0.format() + "\n\n\n\n" + message.format(error=trn_errors.to_html(na_rep="0",escape=False)) + "\n\n\n\n" + message1.format(error=api_errors.to_html(na_rep="0")) + "\n\n\n\n" + message3.format(error=js_errors_by_path.to_html(na_rep="0")) + "\n\n\n\n" + message2.format(error=js_errors.to_html(na_rep="0")))
```

Where message, message1 etc are the html string value...

Comment: If you try `df.to_html(escape=False)`, is the link in the table clickable?

Comment: thats true, it works with escape=False. Thanks !!